# Selectively using yield_content in Padrino application.haml template

Tags: ruby, haml, padrino

In a Haml based Padrino solution I have an `application.haml` like this:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title "blah"
%body
  #header
    = yield_content :headcontent
  #container
    ...
```

For `:headcontent`, in my page (e.g. `index.haml`) I have

```
- content_for :headcontent do
  #headcontent
     %h2= "Index header stuff"
#content
  ...
```

What I want to do is make it so that content pages like `index.haml` can *optionally* specify `- content for :headcontent`.  That is I want `application.haml` to contain some **default** `:headcontent` that only is rendered if a page does not do `- content for :headcontent`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main file, you should be able to use `content_for?`, like this:

```
- if content_for?(:headcontent)
    = yield_content :headcontent
- else
    something else
```